# map id of elements to the values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a list of `ids [1,2,3,4]` and a list of elements duplicated :

```
   l =  ['A','b','A','A','C']
```

I know that :

```
id   value
   1     'A'
   2     'B'
   3     'C'
   4     'D'
```

I want to map the ids to the elements so that the output would be

```
out = [1,2,1,1,3]
```

Comment: First of all it would be great to see some of your intents to get the solution, what code you used and you tried to know what are the way you are following to get the solution. Moreover it would be great to add more information about your doubt and how you want to solve it, [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `df` your DataFrame, use a list comprehension and a mapping Series/dictionary:

```
elems = ['A','b','A','A','C']

s = df.set_index('value')['id']
# or
# s = dict(zip(df['value'], df['id']))

out = [s.get(x.upper()) for x in elems]
```

Or with pandas and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
out = pd.Series(elems).str.upper().map(s).tolist()
```

Output: `[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]`

Used `df`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'value': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **zip** for example:

```
ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
value_dict = {value: id for id, value in zip(ids, values)} # or: dict(zip(values, ids))

l = ['A', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C']
out = [value_dict[value] for value in l]
```

[**Full example here**](http://tpcg.io/_W1QQPE)

Answer (score 1):

```
x = ['A','B','C','D']  #your elements
ids = [1,2,3,4]        #their corresponding ids

d=dict(zip(x,ids))     # you can create a dictionary d

#{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4}  # this is d

l =  ['A','B','A','A','C']

print([d[x] for x in l ])

#output
[1, 2, 1, 1, 3]
```